# Can I decode jpeg byte array to canvas image data without using base64?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing

If I am returning a jpeg in a byte array from an ajax web method call is there a way to decode that byte array into a jpeg image in javascript without using base64?

Comment: With or without? Title says one thing, body says another.

Comment: Sorry, without. Will amend now